# Requiring client certificate causing unexpected disconnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to follow the instructions found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The goal is to get a certificate from the machine calling my Web API service.

I followed the steps and I get an error when I try to load my swagger page in a browser. The browser asks which certificate I want to use, and after I select one, this is the error I get:

> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.

### Details

This is my code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(kestrelServerOptions =>
{
    kestrelServerOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpDefaultsOptions =>
        httpDefaultsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validation Success");                    
                context.Success();    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(context.Exception);    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

    });
    
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}    
app.UseHttpsRedirection();    
app.UseAuthentication();    
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The sections starting with `builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>` and `builder.Services.AddAuthentication` are what the instructions has me add.

When I take out the `builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>` section, it does not have any errors, but does not send the certificate.

I have put breakpoints in both of my `CertificateAuthenticationEvents` events and they do not get hit.

The debug and console output do have anything besides the normal output of a Web API application.

I am hosting in a docker container and running .Net 6.

**What is needed to get this to pass the certificate on to the server?**

Comment: Can you get a Wireshark trace on the handshake?

Comment: @Charlieface - Wireshark is frowned on at my company.  I would have to get permission to use it.  I found a way to at least get past this error.  (See my answer I just posted.)

Comment: What's wrong with Wireshark? It's a perfectly legit debugging tool, just make sure to install the Npcap driver with admin permissions only.

Comment: @Charlieface - it makes our network admins nervous that someone is trying to sniff out ways to hack us. They have ways to detect its use fairly fast.

Answer (score 0):

I added a line after

```
httpDefaultsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
```

The line I added was:

```
httpDefaultsOptions.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
```

And it now got to may event for certificate validation failing.

Comment: Well that's not going to validate the certificate, so you might as well not bother supplying it.

Comment: @Charlieface - true, but if I can get a scenario up and running then I can try to add back in certificate validation afterwards.